# jQuery Accordion and Navigation Issues

Tags: jquery, navigation, accordion

I am working on a site for a client and have run into a problem with the side navigation after adding jQuery Accordion to the main content area of the page.

On this page: http://projectpath.ideapeoplesite.com/rutland/printing-whiteplastisolinks.html if you click on Products in the right hand sub-navigation bar nothing happens. I am not able to determine why it is not responding.

It should "accordion" open same as on this page: http://projectpath.ideapeoplesite.com/rutland/printing-main.html

I would appreciate any assistance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be including the javascript that does that (common.js) which is commented out on the page where it isn't working.

Comment: DEfusion. Thanks for the reply. I actually disable that file to see if it was causing the problem. I have it back in place now and I still have the same issue. If you get another chance please take a peek and let me know what you think. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was a reference to another .js file that was not linked, one of the challenges of fixing other people's work...